# Change UITableView data source on UISearchBar search button click

Tags: ios, list, uitableview, xamarin, datasource

I have a `UITableView` and a `UISearchBar`. When the app loads I pass a certain List to the table source. When I enter a query in `UISearchBar` and hit Search button, I make an API call to fetch a new list.

Now I want to replace the tableview's source with the new List I fetch from the API.

I can filter the list passed initially on `UISearchView` Text change, but I want to supply a completely new list to the table on the search button click.

Is there a way I can change the table source with the new list using the `UISearchView`? or do I need to create a custom search bar?

I have tried passing a null value to the table source and then passing the new list, but that does not do anything.

Any help is appreciated

**EDIT**

MytableViewController

```
Initialize()
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(savedRelatedList))
                {
                    if (CrossConnectivity.Current.IsConnected)
                    {

                        loadingOverlay = new LoadingOverlay(UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds, message);
                        this.View.Add(loadingOverlay);

                        //Fetch Related People
                        var relatedData = await O365Service.GetRelatedPeople(GRAPH_ACCESS_TOKEN);
                        if (relatedData != null)
                        {
                            relatedPeopleList = relatedData.Value.Where(d => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(d.userPrincipalName) && (!d.userPrincipalName.Equals(my_email))).ToList(); ;
                            if (relatedPeopleList != null && relatedPeopleList.Count > 0)
                            {
                                NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.SetString(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(relatedPeopleList.ToList()), "RelatedList");

                            }
                            else
                            {
                                relatedPeopleList = null;
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {

                        }
                        loadingOverlay.RemoveFromSuperview();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        DialogHelper.CreateAndShowDialog("Network Error", "Check your internet connectivity");

                    }
                }

                relatedPeopleList = new List<PeopleRelated>();
                relatedPeopleList.Add(new PeopleRelated { displayName = "Test", });

                searchNewPeopleBar.CancelButtonClicked += delegate
                {
                    searchNewPeopleBar.Text = "";
                    isSearch = false;
                    peopleList = null;
                    tablePeopleSearch.ReloadData();
                    searchNewPeopleBar.ResignFirstResponder();
                };

                var dataSource = new PeopleSearchSource(this);
                tablePeopleSearch.Source = dataSource;
                searchNewPeopleBar.SearchButtonClicked += SearchBar_SearchButtonClicked;
        }   


        searchNewPeopleBar.CancelButtonClicked += delegate
                {
                    searchNewPeopleBar.Text = "";
                    isSearch = false;
                    peopleList = null;
                    tablePeopleSearch.ReloadData();
                    searchNewPeopleBar.ResignFirstResponder();
                };

        private async void SearchBar_SearchButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var searchText = searchNewPeopleBar.Text;
            if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchText))
            {
                isSearch = false;
            }
            isSearch = true;

           //Make api call and get new list
            tablePeopleSearch.ReloadData();
        }
```

PeopleSearchSource

```
public override nfloat GetHeightForRow(UITableView tableView, Foundation.NSIndexPath indexPath)
            {
                return 150;
            }
            public override nint RowsInSection(UITableView tableview, nint section)
            {
                if(peopleHomeController.isSearch)
                {
                    return peopleHomeController.peopleList.Count;
                }
                else
                {
                    return peopleHomeController.relatedPeopleList.Count;

                }

            }

            public override UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
            {
                cell = peopleHomeController.tablePeopleSearch.DequeueReusableCell("people_search_cell") as PeopleSearchCell;


                if(peopleHomeController.isSearch)
                {
                    var data = peopleHomeController.peopleList.ElementAt(indexPath.Row);
                    cell.UpdateCell(data);
                }
                else
                {
                    var data = peopleHomeController.relatedPeopleList.ElementAt(indexPath.Row);
                    cell.UpdateCell(data);
                }


                return cell;
            }
```

Comment: can you understand objective c code?

Comment: @KKRocks Yes I can :)

Comment: Make use of enums and manipulate datasource accordingly.

Comment: @PankajGaikar I am relatively new to iOS. Also I am doing it on Xamarin. I would be great if you could provide me with a sample or some kind of documentation on this

Comment: where is numberRow and cellForRowAtIndexPath ?

Comment: @KKRocks Please see my Edit.  Have added more code

Comment: tableview's methods is looking correct . but you need to call api for filter in SearchBar_SearchButtonClicked function . where i already mentioned that you Make api call and get filter data from server .

Comment: @KKRocks Never mind. I needed to remove UITableView constraints and add them again. some how doing this the GetCell() gets called It works fine now. thanks for  the help. Accepting your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to manage flag on searchBar Delegate.

SearchBar Delegate

```
- (void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar{
    searchBar.text = @"";
    isSearch = NO ;
    [arrFilter removeAllObjects];
    [searchTblView reloadData];
    [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
}

-(void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar{
    NSLog(@"search text :%@",searchBar.text);
    NSCharacterSet *whitespace = [NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet];
   NSString *strSearch = [searchBar.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:whitespace];
    isSearch = YES;
    if ([strSearch isEqualToString:@""]) {
        isSearch = NO;
    }
    // call api here and reload tableview
}
```

TableView Delegate

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    if (isSearch) {
        return arrFilter.count;;
    }
    return arrMain.count;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    NSString *identifier = @"searchCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];

    NSString *strname = [isSearch ? arrFilter :arrMain  objectAtIndex:indexPath.row ]; // change your array here
    UILabel *lblRecipeName = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:101];
    lblRecipeName.text = strname;

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the Answer. I should use just the UISearchView and not the UISearchView with display controller  right?

Comment: it is only search view .

Comment: I tried this solution. But somehow my GetCell() / cellForRowAtIndexPath is not being called. numberOfRowsInSection() gets called though

Comment: did you take two different array ?

Comment: yes. Infact it doesn't get called even on first launch with first list

Comment: Welcome @user3034944.

Comment: can you help me with another question here ?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43631243/not-all-nsuserdefaults-are-restored-on-app-relaunch