# Not all NSUserDefaults are restored on app relaunch

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, nsuserdefaults

I am converting 2 custom lists into a json string and storing it the NSUserDefaults. Something like so:-

```
NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.SetString(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(stationList.Take(50)), "StationList1");
NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.SetString(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(stationList.Skip(50).Take(50)), "StationList2");
```

If I try and retrieve them immediately after saving them like below I get the saved values:-

```
savedStationList1 = NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.StringForKey("StationList1");
  savedStationList2 = NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.StringForKey("StationList2");
```

But the issue is if I restart the app, and try to get the above values in another part of the code, I only get the value for:-

```
savedStationList2 = NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.StringForKey("StationList2");
```

and the value for below is always null :-

```
 savedStationList1 = NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.StringForKey("StationList1");
```

I do not override these values anywhere within the app. Is there a way I can solve this?

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Although natively the iOS system does store data added through 'userdefaults' it may not do this instantly. I would suggest adding the following line:

```
NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.Synchronise();
```

After you store data to standard user defaults run the synchronise and test that you can extract the data, you should find that this will now work correctly for you.

Comment: This only works on the first run. It doesnt on when you rerun the apps. I am starting to think there is something wrong with Binding of library. I assume the purpose of userdefaults is that whatever settings to stored they will be retained on next lunch. This is not the case?

Comment: @Woj it should absolutely store it for the next run, I've not had any problems with it in the past. You should call synchronise() every time you put data into the NSUserDefaults dictionary but you don't need to call synchronise to retrieve the data. If you're having problems there may be an issue with your code.